# Translation especially in graphics

Tags: plotting, graphics

By running the following code:

```
f[x_] = Piecewise[{
  {1/2 x, 0 <= x <= 2},
  {-5 x^2 + 31 x - 41, 2 <= x <= 4},
  {-3/2 x + 9, 4 <= x <= 6},
  {3 x - 18, 6 <= x <= 8},
  {-3/2 x + 18, 8 <= x <= 10}}];

g[x_] = Piecewise[{
  {f[x - 1/5], f'[x] < 0},  
  {f[x + 1/5], f'[x] > 0}}];

Plot[
  {f[x], g[x]},
  {x, 0, 10},
  AxesLabel -> {x, y},
  PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Thick}]
```

I get the following graph:

[image]

Unfortunately it's not exactly what I want. I would like to get this other graph (for now I got with Paint):

[image]

Could someone kindly write me a code to get into what Wolfram Mathematica?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you simply find out the maximum value using Maximize and then create another function? Or you want this process automated?

Comment: try doing like this `g[x_] = Piecewise[{  {{x+1/5,f[x]}, f'[x] < 0},  ..` and use `ParametricPlot`

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is to pick a value to the left if the function is decreasing and a value to the right if the function is increasing because then you'll get a value that's slightly larger. In order to get the flat line over the tops you might instead look for the maximum value in the neighborhood of the current position, it will be the same for the increasing and decreasing parts but will be the maximum in the neighborhood of the maximum.

```
pts = Table[f[x], {x, -0.75, 10.75, 0.001}];
pts = Max /@ Partition[pts, 1000, 100];

Show[
 Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Thick}],
 ListLinePlot[pts, DataRange -> {0, 10}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, ColorData[97][2]}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Looking for the maximum of `f` with constraints at every plot point was time consuming, so instead I evaluate the function at a bunch of points and use those to find the approximate maximum in the neighborhood of width 1 around the plot point.

Answer (score 0):

It is rather slow, but you can define

```
g[x_?NumericQ] := Module[{e}, MaxValue[{f[x + e], -1/5 <= e <= 1/5}, e]]
Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

giving

[image]